# Seleccionar elementos concretos con Javascript en estructuras dinámicas

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas,

Me ha surgido el siguiente problema en la creación de un foro. Los mensajes de cada hilo se cargan de forma dinámica con el siguiente HTML:

```
foreach ($todas_respuestas as $respuestas) {

            echo "<div class='hilo_wrapper_sin_padding'>";
                echo "<div class='info_usuario'>";
                    echo "<div class='info_avatar'>";
                        echo "<a href='#'>" . $respuestas['quien_comenta'] . "</a>";

                        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario = :user");
                        $statement->execute(array(":user" => $respuestas['quien_comenta']));
                        $user = $statement->fetchAll();


                        echo "<div class='avatar'>";
                            echo "<img src='users/" . $user[0]['thumb'] . "' alt='Foto del usuario'>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM hilos_foro WHERE abierto_por = :abierto");
                    $statement->execute(array(":abierto" => $respuestas['quien_comenta']));
                    $hilos_user = $statement->fetchAll();

                    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE quien_comenta = :comentarios");
                    $statement->execute(array(":comentarios" => $respuestas['quien_comenta']));
                    $comentarios_user = $statement->fetchAll();

                    $all_messages = count($hilos_user) + count($comentarios_user);



                    $mes = substr($user[0]['fecha_registro'],5,2);
                    $anyo = substr($user[0]['fecha_registro'],0,4);
                    $meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];

                    echo "<div class='profile'>";
                        if ($all_messages < 100) {
                            echo "<p class='rango'>Novato</p>";
                        } else if ($all_messages >= 100 AND $all_messages < 500) {
                            echo "<p class='rango'>Adicto</p>";
                        } else if ($all_messages >= 500 AND $all_messages < 1000) {
                            echo "<p class='rango'>Mega-adicto</p>";
                        }


                        if ($user[0]['administrador'] == 1) {
                            echo "<div class='administrador'>";
                                echo "<p class='cursiva'><strong>Staff</strong></p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Administrador</strong></p>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        if (!empty($user[0]['de_donde'])) {
                            echo "<p class='mas_info_user'><strong>" . $all_messages . "</strong> mensajes desde <strong>" . $meses[$mes-1] . " " . $anyo  . "</strong> en <strong>" . $user[0]['de_donde'] . "</strong></p>" ;
                        } else {
                            echo "<p class='mas_info_user'><strong>" . $all_messages . "</strong> mensajes desde <strong>" . $meses[$mes-1] . " " . $anyo . "</strong></p>";
                        }

                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='texto'>";

                $fecha_total_actual = $hoy['year'] . "-" . $mes . "-" . $day . " " . $hora . ":" . $minuto;
                $fecha_total_actual = new DateTime($fecha_total_actual);
                $fecha_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],0,16);
                $fecha_apertura = new DateTime($fecha_apertura);
                $anyo_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],0,4);
                $mes_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],5,2);
                $dia_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],8,2);
                $hora_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],11,2);
                $minuto_apertura = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],14,2);
                $interval = date_diff($fecha_apertura, $fecha_total_actual);
                $dia_intervalo = substr($interval->format('%R%a'),1,strlen($interval->format('%R%a')));
                $hora_intervalo = $interval->format('%H');
                $minutos_intervalo = $interval->format('%I');


                $mes = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],5,2);
                $dia = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],8,2);
                $meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];
                $hora = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],11,2);
                $minuto = substr($respuestas['fecha_comentario'],14,2);

                $respuesta_id = $respuestas['ID'];

                $foro_like = $respuestas['foro'];
                $subforo_like = $respuestas['subforo'];


                    echo "<div class='cabecera_post'>";

                        if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 1) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Ahora</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo == 1) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Hace " . substr($minutos_intervalo,1,2) . " minuto</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 10 AND $minutos_intervalo > 1) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Hace " . substr($minutos_intervalo,1,2) . " minutos</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 60 AND $minutos_intervalo >= 10) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Hace " . $minutos_intervalo . " minutos</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $dia_apertura == $day) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Hoy a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura . "</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $dia_apertura == $day-1) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Ayer a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura . "</p>";
                        } else if ($dia_intervalo == 1 AND $dia_apertura == $day-1) {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>Ayer a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura . "</p>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<p class='fecha_publicacion'>" . $dia_apertura . " " . $meses[$mes_apertura-1] . " " . $anyo_apertura . " " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura . "</p>";
                        }


                        echo "<div class='botones_post'>";
                            echo "<p id='resultado'></p>";
                            echo "<form class='corazon_like' name='like' id='heart' title='Me gusta el post' action='foro.php?foro=Xbox%20One&subforo=General&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=1' method='post'>";
                                echo "<input type='checkbox' id='corazon' name='corazon'>";
                                echo "<label class='fa fa-heart no_me_gusta' onclick='myFunction($respuesta_id)' for='corazon'></label>";
                            echo "</form>";
                            echo "<a href='#' title='Borrar post'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
                            echo "<a href='#' title='Reportar post'><i class='fa fa-ban' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";

                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<p>" . nl2br($respuestas['texto']) . "</p>";
                echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";
        }
```

Sé que es un poco largo, la duda que tengo es la siguiente. Tengo unos botones por cada mensaje, para poder borrar, reportar o darle a me gusta. La estructura de los botones es esta, que está incluido en el código de arriba pero para que no lo tengáis que buscar:

```
echo "<div class='botones_post'>";
    echo "<p id='resultado'></p>";
    echo "<form class='corazon_like' name='like' id='heart' title='Me gusta el post' action='foro.php?foro=Xbox%20One&subforo=General&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=1' method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='corazon' name='corazon'>";
        echo "<label class='fa fa-heart no_me_gusta' onclick='myFunction($respuesta_id)' for='corazon'></label>";
     echo "</form>";
     echo "<a href='#' title='Borrar post'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
     echo "<a href='#' title='Reportar post'><i class='fa fa-ban' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Me he dado cuenta que soy incapaz de seleccionar con la clase el elemento correcto. Lo que quiero es que al presionar sobre el botón el `label`me agregue o me quite una clase en función de si el input está seleccionado o no, pero no me acaba de funcionar. El script que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
    $('.corazon_like').click(function(){
    var probando = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-heart');
    console.log(probando);

    if (heart == 0) {
        probando.className += " no_me_gusta";
        heart = 1;
    } else {
        probando.removeClass("no_me_gusta");
        heart = 0;
    }
});
```

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido es usar id en vez de class, pero que se generasen de forma dinámica, si es que eso fuese posible. Estoy bastante perdido y no sé ni para dónde tirar. No sé cómo diferenciar que si pulso sobre le botón de cierto comentario, se ejecute el script sólo en ese comentario, no en todos o ninguno.

El resultado de la variable prueba del script es:

```
HTMLCollection [ <i.fa.fa-heart>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>,<label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta> ]  main.js:27:3
HTMLCollection [ <i.fa.fa-heart>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta>, <label.fa.fa-heart.no_me_gusta> ]
```

Me lo repite dos veces, aunque no sé el motivo.

Comment: Y de dónde sale heart? (No es tan relevante, pero sería bueno saber)

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la variable `heart` está relacionada al contenedor adecuado, tu error está en que para cada selector `$('.corazon_like')` estás operando sobre todos los `.fa-heart` del documento, sin importar si acaso son los que corresponden al contenedor o no.

Segundo, no tiene sentido aplicar métodos de jQuery (.removeClass) sobre algo que no es la salida de una selección de jQuery.

Tu código debiera ser algo como:

```
$('.corazon_like').click(function(){
    var probando = $(this).find('.fa-heart');
    console.log(probando);

    if (heart == 0) {
        probando.addClass("no_me_gusta");
        heart = 1;
    } else {
        probando.removeClass("no_me_gusta");
        heart = 0;
    }
});
```

Pero esta respuesta está incompleta porque no entiendo de dónde sale heart, y si acaso es una variable global, entonces es incorrecto que la manipulación de un contenedor afecte a la variable global. Cada elemento capaz de ser liked o unliked debe manejar su propio estado.

Pienso que tienes que usar la misma query con que generas estos contenedores para establecer el ID de cada post o thread, según corresponda, y asignar identificadores únicos utilizando ese ID. En tu código, por ejemplo, vemos que algunos elementos tienen ID (`resultado`, `heart`) y la iteración que necesariamente saldrá de tu query provocará un montón de elementos con el mismo ID, y eso no va a funcionan nunca.

Lo que debiese haber en cada botonera de like/unlike es algo del estilo:

```
$respuesta_id=$respuestas['id'];
echo "<div class='botones_post'>";
    echo "<p id='resultado_{$respuesta_id}'></p>";
    echo "<form class='corazon_like' name='like' id='heart_{$respuesta_id}' title='Me gusta el post' action='foro.php?foro=Xbox%20One&subforo=General&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID={$respuesta_id}' method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='corazon_{$respuesta_id}' name='corazon' class='corazon'>";
        echo "<label class='fa fa-heart no_me_gusta' onclick='myFunction($respuesta_id)' for='corazon_{$respuesta_id}'></label>";
     echo "</form>";
     echo "<a href='#' title='Borrar post'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
     echo "<a href='#' title='Reportar post'><i class='fa fa-ban' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Y luego declarar un listener para los forms

```
$('.corazon_like').click(function(){
    var probando = $(this).find('.fa-heart');
    console.log(probando);
    var heart=$(this).find('.corazon').is(':checked');

    if (heart == 0) {
        probando.addClass("no_me_gusta");
        $(this).find('.corazon').prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        probando.removeClass("no_me_gusta");
        $(this).find('.corazon').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Finalmente: es redundante usar esta lógica para hacer toggle de un elemento checkbox, cuando éste en sí mismo es un interruptor natural.